# Математический скрипт Bash

Tags: bash, if, echo

И здравствуйте!
Продолжаю пытаться изучать Bash  и есть такое задание.

При запуске надо ввести два числа.
Если 1-е больше 2-го, то они складываются. Если нет - сообщение "Ошибка".
Скрипт я написал и он работает. Вот его содержание:

```
#!/bin/bash  
read -p  "Введите  1-е число:" A  
echo "$A"
read -p "Введите  2-е число:" B
echo "$B"
if [[ $A -gt $B ]]; then
echo "Результат" $(($A+$B));
else
echo  "Error"
fi
```

Но я хочу в начале задать переменную по типу C=$(($A+$B)) и тут получается фигня при запуске скрипта `строка 2: +: синтаксическая ошибка: ожидается операнд (неверный маркер «+»)`

```
#!/bin/bash
C=$(($A+$B))
read -p  "Введите  1-е число:" A
echo "$A"
read -p "Введите  2-е число:" B
echo "$B"
if [[ $A -gt $B ]]; then
echo "Результат" $C;
else
echo  "Error"
fi
```

Если же я убираю $ у А и В `C=$((A+B))`, то ошибки нет, но результат выдает 0 :(
Где я ошибся?

Comment: А как вы хотите сложить значения которые ещё не введены?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Всё работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Складываете переменные до ввода их значений

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь выполнить фрифметическое действие с незаданными переменными. Строка `C=$(($A+$B))` преобразуется в `C=$((+))` т.к. `$A` и `$B` еще не заданы в результате ошибка:

```
bash: +: синтаксическая ошибка: ожидается операнд (неверный маркер «+»)
```

Баш допускает обозначение переменных в арифметических выражениях без `$` в этом случае он ищет переменную с указанным именем и использует её значение для выполнения арифм. действия, если переменная не задана автоматически подставляется `0`. Поэтому конструкция `C=$((A+B))` работает т.к. фактически получается `C=$((0+0))`. Но естественно для выполнения искомой задачи(сложить А и B) это не подходит.

Comment: Да, нашел ошибку, всё работает. Спасибо!