# Bash скрипт сравнения чисел

Tags: bash

Всем привет! Подскажите ,пожалуйста , по данному заданию
При запуске скрипта пользователь вводит два числа.
Необходимо вычесть из большего числа меньшее и вывести результат в консоль.
Если числа равны – умножить их друг на друга (или возвести в квадрат одно из чисел) и вывести результат в консоль.

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Введите первое число" number1

read -p "Введите второе число" number2

if [number2 -gt number1]; then

number3=$((number2 -number1))

echo "$number3"

else 

number4 = ((number1 - number2))

echo "$number4"

fi;
```

Попробовал реализовать так , но выводится всегда 0 и выполняется процедура else .

Comment: [из одного класса одной школы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1486059/178576)

Answer (score 0):

```
read a ;

read b ;

echo "a=$a"

echo "b=$b"

if [ $b = $a ];

then 

i=b*a

echo $i;

if [ $b -gt $a ];

then
let c=b-a;

echo $c

else
let d=a-b;

echo $d

fi;
```

Answer (score 0):

довольно простая задачка которая уместится в однострочнике:

```
read -p "x=" x;read -p "y=" y;z=$[x-y];(( z==0 )) && echo $[x*x] ||echo ${z#-}
```